# How to use path value stored in variable in setwd function in R

Tags: r, rstudio

```
path <- "C:/Users/R studio"

setwd("path/test")

# considering that R studio has directory named as test
```

This setwd function is not working.
Can you please show how to use common path address as a variable in setwd so that if I want to change the directory to other subdirectories of the home path, then I can just append the new part at the end of the variable.
Basically, I want to know how to use variable as a path in setwd.

Comment: assuming test is a directory in R studio `setwd(paste0(path,"/test")` or better yet just drop the `path` variable and pass the full path to `setwd`

Answer (score 1):

you are including path inside the quotation marks..... so it's interpretting as a litteral "path". You want it to be a variable, so outside of the "".

So what you want to say is.

set path to  whatever_path_is + "test".

You do this in R using the paste command... so:

`setwd(paste(path,"/test",sep=""))`

sep=seperator... so what should go between pastes.